# Easy to use player to embed on winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, video, media-player

I need to embed a player that can play video files and use subtitles (.srt).

Which players (with good documentation) are available for this task? And how do I set the file and subtitle to it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant does it have support for .srt files? I could only find that it support closedcaption (SAMIFileName), but nothing related to .srt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround

Add a Windows Media Player COM object.

Add a Timer

```
private Timer playingTimer = new Timer();
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    playingTimer.Enabled = false;
    playingTimer.Tick += renderSubtitles;
}
```

Handle StatusChange to know when it starts to play

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    player.StatusChange += player_StatusChange;
}
```

Activate timer when playing

```
void player_StatusChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (player.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
    {
        playingTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        playingTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Get current seconds from `player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition`, if a subtitle is found make the label visible, set the text and center horizontally. If there aren't any subtitles, hide the label.

```
private void renderSubtitles(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition);
    var entry = entries.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Start <= ts && o.End >= ts);

    if (entry != null)
    {
        subtitle.Visible = true;
        subtitle.Text = entry.Text;
        
        var w = splitContainer.Panel1.Width;
        subtitle.Location = new Point(w / 2 - subtitle.Width / 2, subtitle.Location.Y);
    }
    else
    {
        subtitle.Visible = false;
    }
}
```